# razor MVC Only the first element has been added to the controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following code, When I select multiple departments, it's showing correctly in the front end,
but when it's passed to the back end only the first one has been selected, any idea?

```
                    <div class="form-control-container">
                        <select class="form-control " asp-for="Actioned_DepartmentName" asp-items="Model.Departments" multiple>
                            <option value="">Please select department(s)...</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>


public class ActionedReportRequestDto
{
    public DateTime From { get; set; }
    public DateTime To { get; set; }
    public List<DepartmentType?> DepartmentName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Pls show your model for this.

Comment: Thanks just find out cannot pass a list of enum type, it will always select the first one,
change it to list of string and split it works fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks just find out cannot pass a list of enum type, it will always select the first one, change it to list of string and split it works fine!